# PHP - How to select random tag in the string

Tags: php, string, random

For example, I have this string containing some number of iframe tags (but there can be also some text or links, so the point is to select only iframe tags):

```
<p><iframe frameborder="0" height="180" src="http://www.mixcloud.com/widget/iframe/?feed=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mixcloud.com%2Fskaph%2Fskaphchapeau-rouge-2022014%2F&amp;embed_type=widget_standard&amp;embed_uuid=9ff7c333-5c68-40d6-b9c7-b475c6a8d297&amp;hide_tracklist=1&amp;replace=0&amp;hide_cover=1"  width="600" ></iframe></p>

<p><iframe frameborder="0" height="180" src="http://www.mixcloud.com/widget/iframe/?feed=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mixcloud.com%2Fskaph%2Fx-tract-podcast-night-30-skaph%2F&amp;embed_type=widget_standard&amp;embed_uuid=7186f43a-4bc7-431d-8041-f51366355c44&amp;hide_tracklist=1&amp;replace=0&amp;hide_cover=1"  width="600" ></iframe></p>

<p><iframe frameborder="0" height="180" src="http://www.mixcloud.com/widget/iframe/?feed=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mixcloud.com%2Fskaph%2Fskaphclick-clack-07122013-experiment-liberec%2F&amp;embed_type=widget_standard&amp;embed_uuid=7f2202e6-fd70-45ac-ac1e-6c9dca0ad725&amp;hide_tracklist=1&amp;replace=0&amp;hide_cover=1"  width="600" ></iframe></p>

<p><iframe frameborder="0" height="180" src="http://www.mixcloud.com/widget/iframe/?feed=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mixcloud.com%2FTFSpodcast%2Ftechno-for-soul-podcast-11-mixed-by-skaph%2F&amp;embed_type=widget_standard&amp;embed_uuid=e3f68ffd-488d-4d78-b369-a46c785f59a5&amp;hide_tracklist=1&amp;replace=0&amp;hide_cover=1"  width="600" ></iframe></p>

<p><iframe frameborder="0" height="180" src="http://www.mixcloud.com/widget/iframe/?feed=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mixcloud.com%2Fskaph%2Fskaphtechno-je-v%C5%A1echno-5%2F&amp;embed_type=widget_standard&amp;embed_uuid=2c80035e-27e8-4321-b07d-395e6777b98c&amp;hide_tracklist=1&amp;replace=0&amp;hide_cover=1"  width="600" ></iframe></p>

<p><iframe frameborder="0" height="132" src="http://www.mixcloud.com/widget/iframe/?feed=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mixcloud.com%2Fskaph%2Fskaphtechno-je-v%25C5%25A1echno-vol-2-liberec-experiment-18052013%2F&amp;embed_uuid=f81d24a4-c2f8-4bc5-a10f-7f3fb2243392&amp;stylecolor=&amp;embed_type=widget_standard" width="480"></iframe></p>

<p><iframe frameborder="0" height="132" src="http://www.mixcloud.com/widget/iframe/?feed=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mixcloud.com%2Fskaph%2Fskaphexperiment-18012013%2F&amp;embed_uuid=e63685e9-901c-4d71-a1c5-69d0afb130d6&amp;stylecolor=&amp;embed_type=widget_standard" width="480"></iframe></p>

<p><iframe frameborder="0" height="132" src="http://www.mixcloud.com/widget/iframe/?feed=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mixcloud.com%2Fskaph%2Fskaph-renaissance-winter-mix-2012%2F&amp;embed_uuid=5a7e4685-cf6a-4f84-ba1c-13251d5b7f59&amp;stylecolor=&amp;embed_type=widget_standard" width="480"></iframe></p>

<p><iframe frameborder="0" height="132" src="http://www.mixcloud.com/widget/iframe/?feed=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mixcloud.com%2Fskaph%2Fskaph-mini-technik%2F&amp;embed_uuid=7818bedc-94d0-46b1-8193-4cafcf65ffb5&amp;stylecolor=&amp;embed_type=widget_standard" width="480"></iframe></p>
```

I need to select random iframe tag string from this and I need both opening and closing tag to be included. I suppose I should use something like explode and then use `array_rand()` function, but there is no divider. Other option that came to my mind is regex, but understanding of that still escapes me.

Comment: I think you want to parse the HTML. Try HTML parsers or dom crawlers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular expressions are not suitable for parsing HTML. Use a DOM parser instead -- here's a solution using PHP's native [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument) class:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$iframes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('iframe');

$index = mt_rand(0, $iframes->length);

$random_tag = $iframes->item($index);
```

In the above code, first a random index between 0 and the total number of tags (`$iframes->length`) is chosen with [`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/mt_rand), and then the `item()` method is used to specifically access that tag. Once you have the tag, you can do any further processing. In the demo, I've shown you how to extract the `src` attribute just to show it's random.

[**Online demo**](https://eval.in/106539)

Comment: Thank you, this is the way :) But I cant figure out, how to print the whole tag...it seems that $random_tag is object so this could be the problem...is there a way to transform it into string?

Comment: @MichalS: Sure, it's possible. Simply use `echo $dom->saveHTML($random_tag);`.

Comment: @MichalS: if you're asking about the `saveHTML`, it is used to create an HTML document (or part of it) from a DOM representation. In this case `$random_tag` is the object that has all the information required for us to create the tag and using `saveHTML()` on it would produce the HTML representation of the object (which is the output you're looking for).